# how to cast void* to shared_ptr<mytype>

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, shared-ptr

I have a problem with an OpenGL project, converting from a `void*` pointer to a `shared_ptr<mytype>`.

I am using Bullet to set pointers on the rigid body with:

```
root_physics->rigidBody->setUserPointer(&this->root_directory->handle);
```

The handle is of type `shared_ptr<mytype>`.

The `void*` pointer is returned by Bullet's library function, `getUserPointer()`:

```
RayCallback.m_collisionObject->getUserPointer()
```

To convert back to `mytype`, `static_cast` is not working:

```
std::shared_ptr<disk_node> u_poi = static_cast< std::shared_ptr<disk_node> >( RayCallback.m_collisionObject->getUserPointer() );
```

The error, at compilation time:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:739:39: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘mytype*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Any idea how I can convert from the `void*` returned by `getUserPointer()` to `shared_ptr<mytype>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are storing a *pointer* to an instance of `std::shared_ptr` you need to cast the value returned by `getUserPointer` to `std::shared_ptr<>*` instead of just `std::shared_ptr<>`.

```
std::shared_ptr<disk_node>* u_poi
  = static_cast< std::shared_ptr<disk_node>* >(RayCallback.m_collisionObject->getUserPointer());
```

Comment: While this corrected the error, accessing data from u_poi resulted in another error:
error: ‘class std::shared_ptr<disk_node>’ has no member named ‘name’.
To fix this, i moved the first asterisk before static_cast.
    std::shared_ptr<disk_node> u_poi = * static_cast< std::shared_ptr<disk_node>* >( RayCallback.m_collisionObject->getUserPointer() );

Comment: You need to dereference the pointer (to `std::shared_ptr`) first. `(*u_poi)->name` should do the trick.

Comment: Is this considered common practice/safe? That is, can std::shared_ptr<> be safely stored in void* user pointers provided by libraries? Planning to use this solution but wondered if this solution was more than just an answer to this specific question.

Comment: @MikeWeir Yes, in situations where you need to interface with a C library or poorly thought out C++ library that use `void` pointers in this way it's common. It is not safe however because there are zero checks or guarantees that the pointer is what you think it is. Unless you are required to use a `void` pointer (i.e. interface with a C library) you should avoid this approach and instead use a polymorphic base interface.

Comment: If the same void* is cast to another shared_ptr somewhere else, will the underlying object be deleted twice? I cannot see why this static_cast technique can support proper accounting for the newly minted shared pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I think there a simpler way:

1. change `void*` to `disk_node*`
2. store `disk_node*` in shared_ptr.

Just like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<disk_node> u_poi =
     static_cast<disk_node*>(RayCallback.m_collisionObject->getUserPointer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
example:

```
using MyType = int;
std::shared_ptr<void> void_ptr = std::make_shared<MyType>(0);
std::shared_ptr<MyType> *p = reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<MyType>*>(&void_ptr);//ok
std::shared_ptr<MyType> q = *p; //ok
```

you can  write it in oneline:

```
auto q = *reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<MyType>*>(&void_ptr);
```

//failed below

```
std::shared_ptr<MyType> q =  reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<MyType>>(void_ptr);
```

Answer (score -1):

That's what reinterpret_cast is for:

```
reinterpret_cast<std::shared_ptr<disk_node>*>(RayCallback.m_collisionObject->getUserPointer());
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is unnecessary here and dangerous. Since `std::shared_ptr<disk_node>*` can be implicitly converted to `void*` `static_cast` is more than happy to convert `void*` to `std::shared_ptr<disk_node>*`.

Comment: Inappropriate use of casting here.